# How to pass the state inside a Dynamic URL IN require() method?

Tags: reactjs, image, require, src, react-state

I have to pass a dynamic source in the  element which I was trying to pass by passing the state but it was not working so I tried to load it with

```
this.setState({responseData})
const img = document.getElementById('here');
var imgName= this.state.responseData[0].background;
img.src= require('../../assets/postBackgroundImages/'+ imgName);

 render(){
 return(
 <img id="here"/>
  );
  }
```

It's working fine but I have to pass the data using react map

```
  {this.state.responseData.map((responseData, i) =>   
            <div className={style.postCardContainer} key={i}>
                    <div className={style.postHeader} id="postHeader" key={i}>
                        <div>
                           <p className={style.subject} key={i}>{responseData.subject}</p>
                           <span className={style.topic}  key={i}><a href=""> {responseData.topic} </a></span><BsArrowRightShort/>
                           <span className={style.subTopic} key={i}><a href=""> {responseData.subtopic}</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className={style.menuIcon} key={i}>
                           <div className={style.menuList} key={i}><BsThreeDotsVertical/></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.postImg} onDoubleClick={this.clickedLike} key={i}> 
                        <img src={require('../../assets/postBackgroundImages/'+responseData[i].background)} key={i}/>       
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>)}
```

This way by passing the State in require its not working. Do anybody have any idea of how to pass state in require()

Answer (score 0):

This is My JS Code inside a React Class

```
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.responseData.length-1; i++) {
  var indexOfPost=new String(i);
  const img = document.getElementById(indexOfPost);
  var imgName= this.state.responseData[i].background;
  img.src= require('../../assets/postBackgroundImages/'+ imgName);
  }'
```

And here is the HTML Image Tag

```
{this.state.responseData.map((responseData, i) =>  
<img id={i} key={i} className={style.backgroundImage} />
```

What I am doing is passing a dynamic id(index of the array data) to all the images and then inside a for loop passing getting the respective id after converting the the integer into string. Yes its a trick as you can't pass the state or address & state combination like you address & variable inside require() method

```
 require('../../assets/postBackgroundImages/'+ imgName);
```